# Syntax error and I do not know why Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm getting a syntax error in my code and I can't find the problem

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=f'{data["Prefix"]}')
```

error message:

```
File "C:\test.py", line 22
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=f'{data["Prefix"]}')
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code around it

```
try:
    with open('config.json') as (f):
        data = json.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Configuration file can't be found, please create new one, or move it to folder where your exe of bot is")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=f'{data["Prefix"]}')
token = data["Token"]
Channel = data["Channel"]
AdministratorRole = data["AdministratorRole"]
Stocks = data["StockChannel"]
```

Comment: Which `Python`version you are using? Because f strings are supported only from `Python 3.6`.

Comment: Also, can you show the couple of lines around this code?

Comment: @Dennis.M Also, what about the embedded assignment in the argument position of a function call.  Assignment expressions are PEP-572, and use a `:=` syntax.

Comment: @Dennis.M I'm using Python 3.6

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy sure two secs

Comment: The error you're getting is what you'd see on an earlier version of Python. Add `import sys`, followed by `print(sys.version_info)` to your script to confirm it's running with the version of Python you expect.